# Measuring overlap of two quantum states

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer, quantum-measurements

I have a qubit state $|\psi\rangle = a|0\rangle + b|1\rangle$, and another qubit state $|\psi'\rangle = a'|0\rangle + b'| 1 \rangle$. I want, through quantum gates, to measure the overlap $|\langle \psi | \psi'\rangle|^2$ which is given by a projective measurement $\text{tr}\left[|\psi\rangle\langle \psi||\psi'\rangle\langle\psi'|\right]$. I want to know how to implement this measurement using quantum gates. Also, how would one generalise the measurement to a multi qubit state?

Comment: [Quantum gates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate) are necessarily reversible, and measurements are not - so this would not be possible.

Comment: @MahathiVempati what I mean is how to introduce ancillary qubits or how to control the two qubit states to produce a new state that can be measured, and from which the overlap $|aa'+bb'|^2$ can be deduced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for the [SWAP test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swap_test).

The basic idea is the following: First, the overlap $\omega=\mathrm{tr}[\rho\sigma]$ of two quantum states (e.g. the pure states in your question) is equal to
$$
\omega=\mathrm{tr}[(\rho\otimes\sigma)\mathbb F]\ ,
$$
with $\mathbb F$ the SWAP gate.

On the other hand, the expectation value of *any* unitary gate $U$ in a state $\rho$, $\mathrm{tr}[\rho U]$,  can be estimated using phase estimation.  The simplest version is to apply a controlled-U gate, where the control qubit is initialized in $|+\rangle$ and subsequently measured in the $|\pm\rangle$ basis.  It is an easy exercise to see that the probabilities of the two measurement outcomes are directly related to $\omega$.

Comment: Thanks Norbert, I searched on the Internet the generalised SWAP test and found figure 9 of this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.6814.pdf. I leave it for someone that could have the same question as me in the future

Comment: I confirm that Garcia and Chamorro is the paper that describe the best swap test. However keep in mind that there are some limitations to Swap test especially error : I suggest reading also this paper in details https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/2058-9565/abe458/pdf